# Edit inline style in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, inline-styles

I'm trying to edit the inline style of the Avada WordPress theme, but it's not working. Am I doing something wrong with my selectors?

Here is the HTML code

```
<div class="fusion-column-wrapper" style="padding: 30px;"></div>
```

in the css file for the WordPress theme, I'm trying this to get rid of the padding on mobile devices, but it's not working

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .fusion-column-wrapper[style] {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your css is working below 768px check in which devices you want to apply

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't showing up for me. Maybe I was trying too soon after I updated in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

**remove [style] from your code**

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .fusion-column-wrapper {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
}
```